# Javascript MVVM Organization View empty, ViewModel full of code

Tags: javascript

i always end up having all my code inside my ViewModel because there is nothing that really suits. What should go into the view ? Anybody some examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the library you use. E.g AngularJS (http://angularjs.org) has the ability to use expressions in the views : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

The goal is the have the view based logic (even expressions) in the view. And your business logic in the ViewModel.

Having such expressiveness is missing in certain other libraries e.g in Knockout the view is pretty dumb.